# SQL Server : Procedure showing Timeout expired

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, pivot

I have a procedure in which I am trying to display attendance of each such for each subject. The thing is I am using pivoting to do the required job. Problem I am facing is that on the local host procedure is working fine on local database, but on the server I get this error:

> Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

My procedure looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[prStudentLoadFullAttendance]  
    @SemID int ,
    @CourseID int
AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
    Declare @S  nvarchar(1024)
 Declare @Q nvarchar(Max)


set @S='' 

---code for semester wise attendance
 if(@SemID<>0)
 begin

Select   @S=@S+a.[Column] +',' from
(SELECT  distinct   ISNULL( dbo.tbSubjects.SubCode,'NoColumnName') as [Column] FROM         dbo.tbAttendance INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbAttendanceMaster ON dbo.tbAttendance.MasterAID = dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.AtdID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbAttendance.StID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSubjects ON dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID = dbo.tbSubjects.SubID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSemester ON dbo.tbSubjects.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID
                      where tbSemester.SemID=@SemID ) as a

 set @S=LEFT(@S,LEN(@S)-1)
 print @S

 set @Q='select Name,'+@S+',ODC'+',Percentage'+' from (SELECT  distinct tbStudent.Name,   dbo.tbSubjects.SubCode,
 dbo.fnAttendanceView(dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID,dbo.tbStudent.StudentID) AS Total ,dbo.fnodc(dbo.tbStudent.StudentID) as ODC,
 left(dbo.fnCountTotalAttendance(dbo.tbStudent.StudentID),5) as Percentage

FROM         dbo.tbAttendance INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbAttendanceMaster ON dbo.tbAttendance.MasterAID = dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.AtdID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbAttendance.StID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSubjects ON dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID = dbo.tbSubjects.SubID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSemester ON dbo.tbSubjects.SemID = dbo.tbSemester.SemID 
                      where tbSemester.SemID='+Cast(@SemID as nvarchar(10))+'
                      ) sq
                      pivot(min(Total)   for SubCode IN('+@S+') ) as pt

'
 Execute sp_Executesql @Q
end

---code for course wise attendance
else
 begin

Select   @S=@S+a.[Column] +',' from
(SELECT DISTINCT ISNULL(dbo.tbSubjects.SubCode, 'NoColumnName') AS [Column]
FROM         dbo.tbAttendance INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbAttendanceMaster ON dbo.tbAttendance.MasterAID = dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.AtdID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbAttendance.StID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSubjects ON dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID = dbo.tbSubjects.SubID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbCourse ON dbo.tbSubjects.Course = dbo.tbCourse.CourseID
                      where tbCourse.CourseID=@CourseID ) as a


set @S=LEFT(@S,LEN(@S)-1)
 print @S
set @Q='select Name,'+@S+',ODC'+',Percentage'+' from (SELECT DISTINCT 
                      dbo.tbStudent.Name, dbo.tbSubjects.SubCode, dbo.fnAttendanceView(dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID, dbo.tbStudent.StudentID) AS Total, dbo.fnOdc(dbo.tbStudent.StudentID) AS ODC, 
                      LEFT(dbo.fnCountTotalAttendance(dbo.tbStudent.StudentID), 5) AS Percentage, dbo.tbSubjects.Course
FROM         dbo.tbAttendance INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbAttendanceMaster ON dbo.tbAttendance.MasterAID = dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.AtdID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbStudent ON dbo.tbAttendance.StID = dbo.tbStudent.StudentID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbSubjects ON dbo.tbAttendanceMaster.SubID = dbo.tbSubjects.SubID INNER JOIN
                      dbo.tbCourse ON dbo.tbSubjects.Course = dbo.tbCourse.CourseID
                      where dbo.tbCourse.CourseID='+Cast(@CourseID as nvarchar(10))+'
                      ) sq
                      pivot(min(Total)   for SubCode IN('+@S+') ) as pt
'
 Execute sp_Executesql @Q
end
END
```

Comment: Without knowing **a lot more** about those tables involved (what is their structure? How many rows are stored in them? What kind of indexes do you have on these tables?) and without seeing an **execution plan** - this is **impossible** to answer ....

Comment: Why not use the built in PIVOT?

Comment: see these tables are using default indexing scheme also execution plan is default , its a simple procedure that times out.

Comment: after how much time your query gives timeout ??

Comment: There is no *default indexing* in SQL Server .....

Comment: The problem is likely due to the over use of scalar functions. If possible just put the logic encapsulated by the function directly into the query, or [convert them to inline table valued functions](http://sqlmag.com/sql-server/inline-scalar-functions).

Comment: You may also wish to add a `GROUP BY` to your query to remove duplicates, instead of using `DISTINCT`. The reason I suggest this is that scalar functions are executed RBAR, and when you use `DISTINCT`, the function is executed on every single row, then duplicates removed, whereas using `GROUP BY` will remove duplicates, then execute the function on the distinct results.